# CSS sprite scale to div dimensions

Tags: css, sprite

I was wondering if there is a way to scale a sprite image to the containing div's dimensions
For example, if I have a sprite image with 10 frames (each 100x100 pixels, making it 1000x100)
and the containing div is for instance 200px in width or 50px, is there a way for the frame to be displayed correctly within the div?
Can background-size do anyting there?
Thanks

Comment: Buddy sprites are for gathering small size images into one to scale down the http requests .. Big images will lead to big file size of sprite and it will lead to extended load time of your website .

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CSS3? Because of this you could do following

(HTML)

```
<div class='your-box'></div>
```

(CSS)

```
.your-box {
  background-image: url(.);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

You could test it out over here, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain (w3 schools ftw)

Also I have this in my bookmark, http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts which allow me to see what works for which browser.

If you'd like it to be centered, you cud add to the CSS

```
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-position: center;
```

But as I said, this works for CSS3 and still most people uses IE8 (css is supported by IE9+) but as I said before, have a look which browsers are compitable with CSS3 link again (http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts)

Comment: xm. not quite working. check this http://jsfiddle.net/8Kas3/3/. the top div is how the sprite shows in its original size. the bottom one is with the contain, but that just resizes the whole image to occupy the parent size

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're after. Have you tried http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain ?